Output Data validation with graphql java
Is there a way to validate the data [  apply some filters/rules on the resultset ] extracted in the repository layer by using grahpql?
For example, if  the resultset is a List and for each Object, the validation to be applied are:

Object.field1 is in the date range of 1 year prior to current date and current date
Object.field2 is in the date range of 1 year prior to current date and current date  (or) future date (or) null/blank

I have checked example of writing a DataFetcher by using some argument in the graphql schema. This DataFetcher class is containing the logic to validate the output data. Taken from the url: https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/data-fetching
